# iOS 6/7: is it possible to turn off GPS while keeping the rest (Wifi/cell) running?

Tags: ios, gps, location, location-services

Is it possible to disable/turn off GPS radio and continue receive location using wifi/cell info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS one can not request the location with different provider like one can do it with Android. Based on the accuracy you set, iOS itself takes decision to fetch the location using GPS radio or Wifi/Cell.

You have only option to start and stop GPS. Its up to OS to decide the location provider and feed the application with recent locations.

Comment: "You have only option to start and stop GPS", more precisly you start and stop location service, not GPS!

Answer (score 1):

You can set locationManager.desiredAccuracy to kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers, this usually will shut of GPS, although there is no guarantee.

In cities this will shut down GPS most probably.

In rural area it is less clear what happens because 1000m accuracy cannot always be achieved by cell tower locationing.

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to be 100% sure it's off.

Comment: You can check afterwards in your app whether it was delivered by GPS or not, if this would help I can give info?

Comment: The thing is that I have tried what you suggested and still was getting locations that looked like GPS - accuracy 5/10m. So I guess I need some alternative or confirmation that there is no such thing

Comment: do get a speed value != -1 ? with your current setting (1000m) ?

Comment: Updated try : kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers, then make sure there is not any WLAN reachable. If an WLAN is reachable then ios and Apple may have already stored its possition while GPS was on previously

Comment: You have not answered my question: Is it sufficient to detect that a location was delivered by GPS, or do you want to force GPS to be off?

Comment: I'd like to force GPS to be off. And even if, for any reason, I get accuracy that can be treated as GPS - I need to know that the GPS is still off.

Comment: You cannot force GPS to be off, except you wrap your phone into a alu-foil. That shields GPS, but not GSM cell. (But this is mainly usefull for testing)